# Can i ignore argument type checking in mocked method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mockery

I am writing a test for a service class which is dependant on another service class.

**Foo.php**

```
class Foo {

 public function __construct(Bar $bar)
 {
  $this->bar = $bar;
 }

 public function fooMethod()
 {
  $getSomeArrayOrNull = null;
  $this->bar->barMethod($getSomeArrayOrNull);
 }

}
```

**Bar.php**

```
class Bar {


 public function barMethod(array $array)
 {
   return null;
 }

}
```

**Test.php**

```
class Test extends TestCase {
 public function testIt()
 {
  $bar = Mockery::mock(Bar::class);
  $bar->shouldReceive('barMethod')->withAnyArgs()->andReturn(true);
  $foo = new Foo();
  // this throws an error because invalid argument type in Bar method
  $foo->fooMethod();
 }
}
```

Can i somehow tell mockery to ingore type checking in the `$bar->barMethod()`?
I am writing the unit test and i would like to have this part of the code totaly mocked.

Is this a bad code smell, should i just mock the `$getSomeArrayOrNull` property also? (witch means alyways an array)

Comment: If you don't pass an array to the method change the type definition, or give a default  value?

Comment: Thanks for the input, i have mocked the way that the `$getSomeArrayOrNull` variable was being set.Changing default value or type would not make any sense in that case.